# Microsoft Graph - PHP Rest Example: cURL error 60: SSL certificate

Tags: curl, microsoft-graph-api

I'm actually trying to get this simple example to work, so I can have a working example of Microsoft Graph APIs.

PHP (Rest based code sample) >> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start

After saving the files, adding dependencies using Composer and running WampServer. I get through the starting page, sign-in Microsoft Account, give access/permission and then when the page returns back to localserver , I get these 'cURL' errors.

I've searched over the web and here on Stack Overflow which all suggests me to try to download cacert.pem file and add it to php.ini as (`curl.cainfo="[path]\cacert.pem"`) but it doesn't work with me.

If any of you have tried this sample, then kindly do update me on how to get over this. If I can disable this check, then also how?

[image: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]

Comment: It sounds like you've got a untrusted SSL certificate. Do you have your cert installed and trusted on the machine you're developing on?

Comment: umm.. I thought a trusted cert wasn't required. How can I get it trusted on localhost? Thanks for replying.

Comment: For calling the API you don't, so long as you're calling Graph itself over `HTTPS` Could you provide details for your App Registration and the JSON payloads you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the latest cacert.pem here: https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Make sure to put the file in a path that is allowed by your open_basedir and the file permissions allow PHP to read it. To be sure, you can try:  `echo file_get_contents('/path/to/cacert.pem');` If you don't see the contents of the file, then it is likely a permission issue.
3. Make sure php.ini (for the PHP version you are using) has the following:
   `openssl.cafile="/path/to/cacert.pem"`

Obviously, replace `/path/to/` with something that makes sense for your project. I like to have a directory for private files like `project/data/protected/`